# Creating a python dataframe by parsing JSON API response

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, web-scraping

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363568/cant-get-javascript-generated-html-using-python-selenium-webdriver/53379526#53379526) SO question the OP is unable to scrape a table from a dynamically loaded website. In monitoring the web traffic, via Chrome dev tools, I found that there is an API request made that returns a JSON string with the required info.

The following is the answer I wrote to extract the columns of interest from the API response.

Guide to columns of interest:

1. `Course Title` = `title`
2. `Trainer` = `name` (within `trainers`)
3. `Rating` = `rating`
4. `Vendor` = `name` (within `vendors`)
5. `IT Path` = `path_label` (within `paths`)
6. `Skill Level` = `display` (within `difficulty`)
7. `Course URL` = concatenation of `base` with `seoslug`

The `Vendors` field has missing items hence my use of an `if` statement in the assignment to `vendors`. I am not sure what the usual placeholder value is for missing string values in Python.

I use repeated list comprehensions in loops over the JSON object `data`; where `data = response.json()`

I couldn't think of a way to remove these repeated loops and still have legible code.

I generate a dataframe by joining the lists in a dictionary and then converting with pandas.

I welcome any and all feedback please.

---

**JSON response:**

Example JSON dictionary within response. The response has a collection of such dictionaries.

[image]

---

**Python 3**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


def main():
    base = 'https://www.cbtnuggets.com/it-training/'
    response  = requests.get('https://api.cbtnuggets.com/site-gateway/v1/all/courses/for/search?archive=false')
    
    data = response.json()
    
    titles = [item['title'] for item in data]
    trainers = [item['trainers'][0]['name'] for item in data]
    ratings = [item['rating'] for item in data]
    vendors = [item['vendors'][0]['display'] if len(item['vendors']) != 0 else 'N/A' for item in data]
    paths = [item['paths'][0]['path_label'] for item in data]
    skillLevel = [item['difficulty']['display'] for item in data]
    links = [base + item['seoslug'] for item in data]

    df=  pd.DataFrame(
      {'Course Title': titles,
       'Trainer': trainers,
       'Rating': ratings,
       'Vendor': vendors,
       'IT Path': paths,
       'Skill Level': skillLevel,
       'Course URL': links
      })

    #print(df)
    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False )

if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    main()
```

Comment: The only thing I'll say is that, if each publication on Code Review had a presentation as clear, complete and pleasant as yours, the overall quality of this site would be improved. Pretty nice code BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I couldn't think of a way to remove these repeated loops and still have legible code.

There is a way:

```
titles, trainers, ratings, vendors, paths, skillLevel, links = zip(*((
    item['title'],
    item['trainers'][0]['name'],
    item['rating'],
    item['vendors'][0]['display'],
    item['paths'][0]['path_label'],
    item['difficulty']['display'],
    base + item['seoslug']
) for item in data))
```

I haven't tested this, so you should.

Comment: Sorry for delay. If I replace with  _item['vendors'][0]['display'] if len(item['vendors']) != 0 else 'N/A'_ ,   this works beautifully. This is basically where I was trying to get to. Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of the * in the above please? Is it unpacking?

Comment: @QHarr Yes, it's the unpacking operator.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of splitting the data into a separate variables by column, you could convert each JSON object into a flat dictionary using a function similar to this

```
def course_dict(item):
    return {'Course Title': item['title'],
            'Vendor': item['vendors'][0]['display'] if item['vendors'] else None,
            # and so on
            }
```

and construct the dataframe using

```
data = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame([course_dict(item) for item in data])
```

Keeping related data together makes the code easier to follow. Also, since your final output is a csv file, you could skip the dataframe and use `csv.DictWriter` instead.

> I am not sure what the usual placeholder value is for missing string values in Python.

`None` is the usual placeholder for missing values of any type.

Comment: Thanks. How would I expand this for the other items? Create a series of functions?

Comment: @QHarr Just expand the function, adding the other items next to the two

Answer (score 2):

The only major thing I would change is that:

```
if len(item['vendors']) != 0
```

Is the same as:

```
if item['vendors']
```

Because an empty list will return back as False. If you want to try it out:

```
a = []
bool(a)      # False
b = [1,2,3]
bool(b)      # True
```

I would also be careful with what you have because those dictionaries that you are converting might have more than one value, in which case you would miss them. This is the line that I am referring to:

```
    paths = [item['paths'][0]['path_label'] for item in data]
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Great point about vendors. And yes, I made an assumption, that the first value would suffice, for the other line you pointed out about dictionaries. +